# xrdp on centos7 can't connect

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, xrdp

I have installed xrdp on centos 7 using this guide [guide](https://hostpresto.com/community/tutorials/using-a-desktop-environment-on-a-centos-7-vps/)

```
  netstat -antup | grep xrdp
    tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:3350          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3096/xrdp-sesman
    tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:3389            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      3097/xrdp
```

So it means that it works, but when I try to connect to xrdp, after login I see this:

```
login succesfful for display 10
VNC started connecting
VNC connecting to 127.0.0.1 5910
VNC error - problem connecting
some problem
```

Log file for xrdp:

```
[20170505-20:56:42] [INFO ] A connection received from 127.0.0.1 port 33004
[20170505-20:56:43] [INFO ] ++ created session (access granted): username root, ip my_ip:13473 - socket: 12
[20170505-20:56:43] [INFO ] starting Xvnc session...
[20170505-20:56:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:5910)
[20170505-20:56:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6010)
[20170505-20:56:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 9 (AF_INET 0.0.0.0:6210)
[20170505-20:56:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20170505-20:56:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 7 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20170505-20:56:43] [DEBUG] Closed socket 8 (AF_INET 127.0.0.1:3350)
[20170505-20:56:43] [INFO ] Xvnc :10 -auth .Xauthority -geometry 3840x2048 -depth 24 -rfbauth /root/.vnc/sesman_root_passwd:10 -bs -nolisten tcp -localhost -dpi 96
[20170505-20:56:43] [CORE ] waiting for window manager (pid 3029) to exit
[20170505-20:56:43] [CORE ] window manager (pid 3029) did exit, cleaning up session
[20170505-20:56:43] [INFO ] ++ terminated session:  username root, display :10.0, session_pid 3028, ip ip_goes_here:13473 - socket: 12
```

I can't undestand problem behind this, any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that you need display (session) manager configured properly.

Try this:

1. yum groupinstall "Server with GUI"  //it's installed gnome and all staff include gnome-session
2. check gdm.service - systemctl status gdm // should be enabled